# STM32F4 HAL SPI_Receive dma just receive one time

Tags: stm32, spi, dma, hal, stm32f4

I tried many methods and read reference, but i could not correctly read data from SPI_Receive_DMA mode.

In spi 1 , I want to continuously read Ad7606 data via spi in dma mode in one thread .
However, I always received same data in SPI1 dma mode . As if i didn't receive any new data. i know that if i just want to receive data in spi dma mode ,i have to also turn on TX and RX DMA channels.
i do not know which step i miss or wrong . Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks for very much .

```
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
 
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{
 
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();
 
  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Stream4_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream4_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream4_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Stream0_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Stream3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream3_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream3_IRQn);
 
}
** Note 
DMA2_Stream0 - > SPI1 Receive
DMA2_Stream3 - > SPI1 Transmit
DMA1_Stream4 - > SPI2 Transmit

void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* hspi)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(hspi->Instance==SPI1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_MspInit 0 */
 
  /* USER CODE END SPI1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_SPI1_CLK_ENABLE();
 
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**SPI1 GPIO Configuration
    PA5     ------> SPI1_SCK
    PA6     ------> SPI1_MISO
    PB5     ------> SPI1_MOSI
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 
    /* SPI1 DMA Init */
    /* SPI1_RX Init */
    hdma_spi1_rx.Instance = DMA2_Stream0;
    hdma_spi1_rx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_3;
    hdma_spi1_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_spi1_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_spi1_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_spi1_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_spi1_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_spi1_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_spi1_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
    hdma_spi1_rx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi1_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }
 
    __HAL_LINKDMA(hspi,hdmarx,hdma_spi1_rx);
 
    /* SPI1_TX Init */
    hdma_spi1_tx.Instance = DMA2_Stream3;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_3;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_spi1_tx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi1_tx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }
 
    __HAL_LINKDMA(hspi,hdmatx,hdma_spi1_tx);
 
    /* SPI1 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI1_IRQn, 5, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_MspInit 1 */
 
  /* USER CODE END SPI1_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_TIM7_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  uint8_t receive_buffer[256] ;
  /* Init scheduler */
  osKernelInitialize();
 
 /*handle */
  SendTaskHandle = osThreadNew(SendTaskFun, NULL, &SendTask_attributes);
  ReceiveTaskHandle = osThreadNew(ReceiveTaskFun, NULL, &ReceiveTask_attributes);
 
  osKernelStart();
  while (1) {
  }
}
 
 
 
void ReceiveTaskFun(void *argument)
{
  for (;;) {
     //-- SPI1 callback 
    HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(&hspi1); 
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIO_A, GPIO_PIN_7, 1); //-- cs=1    deactive 
}
 
 
 
void DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_spi1_rx);
}
 
void DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_spi1_tx);
}
 
 
void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
   if (hspi->Instance == SPI1){
         //-- Enable CS
         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIO_A, GPIO_PIN_7, 0); //-- cs=0   active low  

         //- -  SPI2_DMA_receive
         ...... (Here is for receive data from AD7606 )
     HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi1, receive_buffer, 8);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your functions are mapped correctly, current flow seems to be:

1. ReceiveTaskFun calls HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback() which asserts your chip select, starts DMA transfer and returns
2. ReceiveTaskFun() deasserts your CS pin and goes into next loop.
3. HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback() (called from ReceiveTaskFun)  again asserts your CS pin and tries to set up DMA transfer and, most likely, fails. Check return value to see HAL_BUSY, because it hasn't finished transmitting
4. Meanwhile your DMA transfer might happen, might not (peripheral will be transmitting, whether your slave clocks out data or not), because you are toggling CS pin
5. When transfer of 8 bytes is done, HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback() is called, which reasserts CS pin and starts DMA transfer. This might succeed, but since you are toggling CS pin all the time, all you get is garbage

Solution(s) could be:

1. Use delay in ReceiveTaskFun(). You know transmit + capture duration, use that as a basis
2. Use RTOS signalling from SPI interrupt - make your ReceiveTaskFun waits for signal from ISR callback and then set up new transfer.